# Dealing with gzip encoded GET/OAUTH response in R

Tags: r, api, oauth, rstudio

I'm new to both: R and OAUTH. I've learned a little using coursera examples on github API where OAUTH request gave plaintext response but now I'm trying to do something that is practicall for me and access EVE-Online CREST OAUTH API but instead of what I got when I tried github API (im using "httr" libary):

```
Response [https://api.github.com/users/jtleek/repos]
  Date: 2014-12-14 08:57
  Status: 200
  Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 154 kB
[
  {
    "id": 12441219,
    "name": "ballgown",
    "full_name": "jtleek/ballgown",
    "owner": {
      "login": "jtleek",
      "id": 1571674,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1571674?v=3",
      "gravatar_id": "",
...
```

I got this BINARY BODY response:

```
Response [https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/market/10000002/orders/buy/?type=https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/types/185/]
  Date: 2014-12-14 08:05
  Status: 200
  Content-type: application/vnd.ccp.eve.MarketOrderCollection-v1+json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 7.61 kB
<BINARY BODY>
```

And frankly I have no idea what to do with it. I'm preety sure its gzip (I used chrome extension postman to access the same information and header says its encoded with gzip) but I dont know how to uncompress it, maybe there is standard way of dealing with binary/gzip response but my google foo have failed me.

Here is exact code I'm running:

```
library(httr)
myapp <- oauth_app("my app name redacted", "my id redacted", "my secret redacted")
eve_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoint(authorize = "https://login-tq.eveonline.com/oauth/authorize/",access = "https://login-tq.eveonline.com/oauth/token/"), myapp, scope = "publicData")
token <- config(token = eve_token)
req <- GET("https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/market/10000002/orders/buy/?type=https://crest-tq.eveonline.com/types/185/", token)
```

EDIT:
YES!!! :)
managed to figure it out :)

```
result <- content(req, type = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
```

while the reqular content(req) produced just raw binary data, the above translated it to json :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I wrote above, what I needed to do was pass more information about content type and encoding used to content function like this:

```
result <- content(req, type = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
```

gzip part as its turned out was handled automagically, but the issue was strage content-type used by EVE API. when i explicitly passed desired content type R was able to read data as json without problem